# Can't change cite color from magenta to black

Tags: hyperref, color, citing

I have a problem with changing cite colours on my thesis (I am using citep{namecite}). The current colour is magenta and whatever setting I do, in order to make them black, fails. Do anyone know what can I do with that? This is my current code setting:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
\addbibresource{Bibliography}% The filename of the bibliography
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ 
       colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=black, 
       citecolor=black,
       filecolor=black,
       menucolor=black,
       pagecolor=black,
       urlcolor=black,
       breaklinks=true
}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[]\year{yr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow, arydshln}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Comment: Could you please turn your code fragment into a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that reproduces the issue you describe? Finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.

Comment: Some additional remarks concerning the code you already posted: Please keep in mind the correct loading order of packages. Generally, the packages `hyperref` and `cleveref` should be loaded last. Also please reconsider if you really need all the packages you load. For example, you don't need `graphics` if you also load `graphicx`. Also don't load packages twice (e.g. `fontenc`, `longtable`, `multirow`, `tabularx`,...)

Comment: Also if you load `[table]{xcolor}`, there is no need for `colortbl` and `color`.

Comment: Also, add `breaklinks` only in an emergency or if the document is not viewed but printed. If the driver does not support broken links, then the link areas of the broken links will be utterly wrong. The feature is enabled anyway, if the driver supports it.

Comment: I don't think you need your `\hypersetup` at all `hidelinks` will already do what you want. If I add `\documentclass{article}` to your preamble, move `cleveref` to avoid an error and add a document body like `\begin{document}\citep{sigfridsson,appleby}\printbibliography\end{document}` I get a document with all black citations - no other colours involved.

Comment: That means we need to see an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to be able to help you.

Comment: Since you seem to want "black" for all hyperlinks, you might as well set the option `allcolors=black`; that's simpler than setting six separate color options, right?

Comment: I have tried with the option allcolors=black but it did not help. I have change everything you suggested and what I have found out from other question but I still have the same proble. my dicumenclass is not article,  I have put the setting for my masters thesis. Thank you for your help

Comment: The `hyperref` package should most definitely be loaded next-to-last, *not* early on in the preamble. And, the `cleveref` package should be loaded last. Please make those changes and see if they matter for the color of hyperlinked citation call-outs.

Comment: Off-topic: Unless your bib file is called `Bibliography` (note: no extension), writing `\addbibresource{Bibliography}` isn't right. Assuming the filename has extension `.bib`, the proper directive is `\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}`.

Comment: Another off-topic comment: Loading both `mathpazo` and `lmodern` makes no sense. Employ one font package or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: You shouldn't use this template.

Comment: If you really want to use LaTeX and templates, you need to read an introduction first. Adding to the bad template, you put all kinds of stuff that you seemed to have problems with. You won't have much luck this way writing your masters or doctoral thesis.